# Travelling with infant who stops being an infant during the trip (turns 2)

Tags: air-travel, children, pakistan, saudi-arabia

I'm a Canadian PR my family (wife, kid) are Canadian Citizens, we're travelling to Pakistan via Jeddah (Saudi Airline). We're staying in Jeddah for 1 week and then going to Lahore (Pakistan) for 2 weeks, now my kid is still considered infant (he will turn to 2 at April 17th, 2014) my travel agent booked our itinerary from Lahore(Pakistan) to Jeddah on 18th of April and then back to Toronto on the 19th, so he'll turn 2 by the time we board the returning bound flight, I asked my travel agent if there will be any issue and she said she got a special permission from Saudi Airlines that they are giving him 1 day grace period and will still consider him as in infant to board the flight.

As far as I know after a kid turns 2, he's no longer considered an infant and have to pay almost 75% of the airfare? Is that true?

Comment: For many airlines, the rules on age apply based on the age at the time of the first flight. Have you tried asking the airline in question what their rules are?

Comment: Upto age 2 kid is consider infant and only paying almost 20% of the airfair but is it possible to get a grace period from an airline as an agent?

Comment: On BA [a child who's 2 or more needs their own seat, but if they start the trip as an infant that seat is free](http://www.britishairways.com/en-gb/information/family-travel/planning-your-trip) (but you have to phone up to book as it's a special case). Other airlines may do the same, best check with your airline

Comment: Get that in writing. I remember a news story here involving an Air Canada reward ticket and a child who turned 2 during the trip - lot of stress, parents had to buy the child a last minute ticket, only public outcry got them a refund.

Comment: Thanks @KateGregory, I'll ask my travel agent to do so. BA is doing good job but I'm not sure about Saudi Airline, anyway thanks guys for your suggestions.

Comment: This question. This question right here. The only question except the OK we're all X here series, which made me chuckle.

Answer (score 7):

While [this Saudi Airlines page says](http://www.saudiairlines.com/portal/site/saudiairlines/menuitem.d9a467d070ca6c65173ff63dc8f034a0/?vgnextoid=f1313a4cd8ac7110VgnVCM1000001f64e80aRCRD):

> If the infant reaches the age of 2 years prior to their return journey, they must pay the applicable child fare, taxes, fees and charges for that part of the journey.

In reality things are different, as long as the ticket is issued then it is ok and no one checks and the system only checks the date of the infant as of the first sector.

Comment: @Nadeem, I am 100% positive of this, but please feel free to update us to confirm this for future readers.

Comment: I asked my travel agent and she's like I assured you I already confirmed from Saudi Airline, so don't worry, they won't check from Pakistan and once the boarding passes has been issued, they don't bother to check for 1 day difference if he's infant or child.
Now I'm okay with that but the issue is we're getting connecting flight from Jeddah(Saudi Arabia) to Toronto, will  they check (date and age) again while boarding to a different aircraft?

Comment: @nadeem no one will check. The one who is suppose to check is the reservation agent... As long as the reservation is made then its ok.

Answer (score 6):

I came back without any issue :)

Comment: +1 for coming back to confirm!  But future readers, please do check with your airlines, not all will be as flexible.

Comment: Yes for sure, but in my case, they don't even bother to check the passport date of birth on both Airports (Lahore, Pakistan and Jeddah, Saudia Arabia) at first when we're waiting on counter for immigration officer, I was a bit confused if they ask: he is no more infant... but the officer was a laid back person, take a sneak peak of my kid, sparkle him a smile and gave back our (Canadian) passports.
It was a nice experience except connecting flight at Jeddah airport :( especially if you're waiting in lounge with a toddler and not enough space for him to run around.